# Can lemurs catch me while I’m grinding?

Tags: altos-odyssey

In the original *Alto’s Adventure*, if an Elder was chasing me they wouldn’t be able to catch me if I was grinding on a rail.

In *Alto’s Odyssey* the Elders were replaced by Lemurs who leap up to vines to follow close behind me while I’m grinding.

Can Lemurs catch me while I’m grinding on vines, or am I only in danger while I am on the ground?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, they can catch you while you're grinding.

When you are grinding and do not jump at all throughout the grinding process they close up the distance between them and you and eventually jump on you. However, even a simple jump now and then should keep them away from knocking you down from the grind.

Source: personal experience